How do I setFocus to a MudTextField that is embedded in a Child Component?
I have a .razor page (Parent) that contains a child Component which is a MudTextField.  When the user navigates to the Parent Page I want the Focus / Cursor to be in the MudTextField.  How do I get the reference of the MudTextField in the Child to the Parent?
Note: I noticed I spelled Parent incorrectly in my code.  I corrected this after taking the screenshots.
Thank you
Child Component within the Parent

EventCallBack in the Parent

MudTextField in the Child Component

Child Function to Parent


In your component add a FocusTextField method
    public async Task FocusTextField()
    {
        await refUserInputField.FocusAsync();
    }

Then when instantiating your component use a ref to it like
<TestComponent @ref="testComponentRef" />
@code {
  private TestComponent testComponentRef;
}

Then to trigger it just await testComponentRef.FocusTextField()
